# Android: RectF params in custom View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom view where I'm drawing pie chart. The chart is drawing in RectF. But if I want to create RectF I need to set xLeft,xRight,yTop,yBottom params...But I dont knwo this params !! My custom view will be included in linearLayout with height and wight fill parent. So how to be ?

```
public class PieChart extends View {
private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private float[] value_degree;
private int[] COLORS;
RectF rectf;

public PieChart(Context context, float[] values, int colors[]) {

    super(context);
    value_degree = new float[values.length];
    COLORS = colors;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        value_degree[i] = values[i];
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    rectf = new RectF(// I dont want to hardcode coordinates here);

    for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++) {
        paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
        canvas.drawArc(rectf, 270 + 90 * i, value_degree[i], true, paint);
    }
}
```

}

And in my Actitivy

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pie_chart);
 linearLayout .addView(new PieChart(this, someValues, someColors));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the `PieChart` object you pass it an array, the `value_degree`. Use the size of this array to predetermine the size or your `RectF`. You could implement a constant relation in between the 2 (ie. `rectfHeight = 5 * value_degree.lenght`), or create some sort of a variable dynamic relation.